# как лучше сверстать слайдер в картинке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Вот как должно выглядеть , сам слайдер это цветная картинка, серый фон статичный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше это сверстать , чтобы в итоге было адаптивно , на всех экранах и фулл ширина, юзаю слик слайдер , если что могу подключить любой другой.

Answer (score 0):

@s1mple Здравствуйте если Вам нужна карусель адаптивно можно использовать плагин к примеру этот 
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/
Заходите на сайт выбираете demos, к примеру basik там будет responsive который отвечает за адаптив 
К примеру цифра 600 это ширина
items:3 - это кол-во слайдов